# Use method from superclass as "decorator" for subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a scenario where I want to "mark" methods in a subclass in python to basically say "wrap this subclass method inside a method in the superclass"

For example:

```
class SuperClass:
    ...
    def wrapping_method(func):
        # do something in the SuperClass instance before the method call
        func(args)
        # do something in the SuperClass instance after the method call
    ...

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    ...
    def my_function(args):
        # do something in the SubClass instance
    ...
```

I want it so that whenever I call `my_function(args)` in SubClass, the `wrapping_method()` in SuperClass is called instead with the method `my_function` passed in as an argument (with all of the `my_function` arguments somehow).

I am unfamiliar with how things like decorators can be used here but I would like to be able to use some kind of annotation-like '@' notation to 'mark' subclass methods.

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you encounter? Decorators and inheritance are orthogonal. You can directly decorate the subclass method with the superclass method (note that it should be a classmethod), e.g. ``@SuperClass.wrapping_method
def my_function(self, args): ...``

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Your new code comments (operating on instances) conflict with your description (operating on classes). There generally isn't a specific SuperClass instance when you have a specific SubClass instance and vice versa.

Comment: In the SuperClass I want to update fields both before and after the method call to `my_function` in the SubClass. I just used the word instance to indicate fields which are declared in the SuperClass constructor are being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using decorators and subclassing is orthogonal. You can define a decorator in a base class method (or anywhere you like) and apply it to a sub class method (or anywhere you like).

```
class SuperClass:
    """Type that counts invocation of methods decorated with @counted"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    # define decorator by taking one callable as argument
    @staticmethod
    def counted(method):  # 1
        """Decorate a method to count its invocations"""
        def counted_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.count += 1
            bound_method = method.__get__(type(self), self)  # 2
            return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
        return counted_method

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    # use `@decorator` to decorate a method
    @SuperClass.counted
    def my_method(self):
        print("doing something in the SubClass instance")
```

Here, `counted` is a regular decorator, meaning it just takes some callable (`#1`) and performs *some* operation on it -- in this example, wrapping it. Since the `counted_method` wraps around the actual method, we must [manually invoke the descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) (`#2`) to emulate method lookup.

```
>>> instance = SubClass()
>>> instance.count
0
>>> instance.my_method()
doing something in the SubClass instance
>>> instance.count
1
```